# "The associations between x and y " vs "The associations of x with y"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, logic

When conducting and reporting a statistical analysis, is it more correct to state:

1. "The associations *between* x and y "
2. "The associations *of* x with y"?

Or are both equally correct? 1) seems more logical, but can be awkward to word when several predictors are applied.

Comment: What is the full context?

Comment: Is it a one-way or two-way relation?

Comment: For instance, the associations of density and street layout with the propensity to walk.

Comment: Please [tag your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/tagging). Doing so helps people to understand its context, helps people to find it when searching for particular kinds of questions, etc. (I know that this question was migrated, but now that it's here . . .)

Comment: As a matter of clarification, your use of the plural "associations" suggests either or both of "x" and "y" refer to some complex set of variables rather than single variables.  Please, then, explain what you mean by "x" and "y" in the context of a statistical analysis.

Comment: Either can be correct . . . .  depending on context.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be better asked on Mathematics.SE.  I'd use 'the association between x and y' (note the singular), modelling after (the more exactly defined) 'the relation between x and y'.

Comment: For outcome x, x can be singular (logistic regression; e.g., unimodal mode choice) or plural (ordinal regression, categorized walking frequencies). As for the predictor y, y can indeed comprise several predictors. Judging by the literature in my field, both variations seem to be used equally, and often both can be found within the same publication.